# Get true values from object

Tags: javascript

In the code above i try to get the object with only true values, so i expect to get:

```js
 {
      _id: 'userId',
      username: 'username',
 };
```

```js
const newb = {
  _id: 'userId',
  username: 'username',
  password: undefined
};
const object2 = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(newb)
      .map(([ key, val ]) => {
        console.log(val)
        if(val !== undefined) {
          return [key, val]
        }
      })
);
console.log('Success:', object2);
```

But now i get: `Iterator value undefined is not an entry object`. How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to iterate over object's own enumerable property names (keys) instead of using `Object.entries()` and `Object.fromEntries()`.

```js
const newb = {
  _id: 'userId',
  username: 'username',
  password: undefined
};
const result = {};
Object.keys(newb).forEach(key=>{
    if (newb[key] !== undefined)
      result[key] = newb[key];
});
console.log('Success:', result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Every JavaScript function returns `undefined` by default. So, your mapping function returns `undefined` if `val === undefine` because there is no `else` statement returning a valid result.

Answer (score -1):

You need to filter out the `undefined` properties:

```js
const newb = {
_id: 'userId',
username: 'username',
password: undefined
};
const object2 = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(newb)
        .filter(([key,val]) => val != undefined)
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
);
console.log('Success:', object2);
```

Comment: @charlietfl yep removed just now

Answer (score -1):

```js
const newb = {
  _id: 'userId',
  username: 'username',
  password: undefined
};

const object2 = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(newb).filter(entry => entry[1] != null));

console.log('Success:', object2);
```